# User Ionicons email-unread

Tags: tabs, icons, ionic-framework, symbols, ionicons

I am trying to use an icon from Ionic that on this website:
http://ionicons.com/

It's the "ion-email-unread" somehow this an multiple other Icons just do not work.
They simpley do not show when I call them. There is not error Message.

My code looks like this:

```html
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top {{footerClass}}">

    <!-- Home Tab -->
    <ion-tab title=" Home " icon="icon ion-home " href="#/tab/home ">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-home "></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <!-- Chat Tab -->

    <ion-tab title="Chat {{emailIcon}}" icon="ion-email-unread"  href="#/tab/chat-master ">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-chat-master "></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>


    <!-- Coins Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="Coins " icon="icon ion-social-usd " href="#/tab/coins ">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-coins "></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <!-- Settings Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="Settings " icon="icon ion-ios7-gear " href="#/tab/settings ">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-settings "></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

If I put icon="ion-email" which represents a different symbol, it works just fine.

Can you help me to find my issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## What's wrong

It appears that the Ionic framework is running on an older version of Ionicons. If you look at the css file for ionic, `css/ionic.app.css` and go to line 548, you would expect to see something along the lines of:

```
.ion-email-unread:before {
  content: "\f3c3"; }
```

Unfortunately this is not the case. I tried adding that snippet in manually and it appears the fonts themselves don't actually have the email-unread icon in them yet.

## Solution

Until Ionic updates which Ionicons it includes in the framework, you could do the following:

1. Head over to [Ionicons Repo](https://github.com/driftyco/ionicons/) and download that directly.
2. Copy the contents to your `www/lib` folder.
3. Include the new Ionicons css into your app by adding the following to your index.html right under the existing `ionic.app.css` include.

```
<link href="lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This **should** solve your issues with the email-unread icon not showing.

## Alternate Solution

One thing you will find is that the email and email-unread icons were not designed too great as the unread version is centred based on the full width including the dot on the corner of the envelop, this causes the icon to shift slightly when it is changed from email to email-unread and vice versa.

To overcome this slight nuisance I would recommend using badges on your tab to indicate something being unread. It's as simple as adding the `badge="1"` to the `ion-tab` element to indicate 1 unread message. and it looks more native as well. [Here's and image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJW1l.png).